# One click button access to azure resource manager for customers

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is it possible currently to make an application in my Azure AD tenant and allow customers to give it permission to alter their resource groups.

I basically want to create an web application that allows any azure resource owner to allow my application to add something to a resource group of their choosing.

I cant figure out if its required for the customer to have the global administrator role for this to work?

Is it possible to make a flow that lets the customer sign in to my webapp, and give permission for a resource group of this choose, without him being the global administrator.

Is it possible for something in the azure portal to select his resource group add allow my azure ad application to get access to his resource group, or what is needed from the customer for this to be possible?

Comment: Some follow up questions: 1) Do you want the users of your application to add something to their resource groups only when they use your application or would you want your application to make the changes even when the user is not present? 2) Do you want access restricted to only one resource group or any resource groups the user of your application has permission to?

Comment: 1) Is there any restrictions to get refresh tokens if first they give permision?, to answer your question. If possible i would like do do checks on the resource group also when the user is not active in my application. 2) If its possible to allow the user to only give me access to one RG, then i hope its easier to get the user to adopt it (knowing i dont have access to his full subscription).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways by which a 3rd party application can access a user's subscription:

1. **Delegated Permission (User Impersonation)**: Azure Portal is a good example of that. Basically in this scenario, a user logs in into your application by authenticating herself/himself against their Azure AD and then your application makes ARM API calls on behalf of the logged in user. If the user has permission to do something, your application will do that otherwise your user will get an error.
2. **Application Permission**: This is basically more for running things in the background when the user is not logged in. Essentially this is where the concept of `Service Principal` comes in. In this scenario, someone with administrative privileges grant certain permissions to your application and then your application will be able to do things it is permitted to do. The user need not be present in this scenario.

Now coming to your questions:

> I basically want to create an web application that allows any azure
>   resource owner to allow my application to add something to a resource
>   group of their choosing.
>
> I cant figure out if its required for the customer to have the global
>   administrator role for this to work?

Yes, it is possible for your to create such a web application and the customer need not be a global administrator to use such an application. In fact, this is how we're providing Azure Subscription management in Cloud Portam. Azure Portal works the same way. When you login into Azure Portal, you only do things you have permissions to. To see this in action, just login into Azure Portal using a user who is in Reader role and try to create some resources.

> Is it possible to make a flow that lets the customer sign in to my
>   webapp, and give permission for a resource group of this choose,
>   without him being the global administrator.

Yes, it is entirely possible however the permission from Azure's perspective will be at Subscription level and not at a resource group level. Again since you would be impersonating the user, the user need not give you explicit permission to access certain resources. Azure RBAC will take care of this for you.

> Is it possible for something in the azure portal to select his
>   resource group add allow my azure ad application to get access to his
>   resource group, or what is needed from the customer for this to be
>   possible?

Yes, it is possible to do so. However in this case, the user who's granting the permission to your application should be in a role that allows her/him to perform this operation. They should have write permission on `Microsoft.Authorization` resource provider. However please do keep in mind that once your application (also known as `Service Principal`) is granted access to a resource  in your user's subscription, there's no need for a user to login. You typically would want to use this approach for background process kind of applications.

Comment: when doing user impersonation, in the grant permision step, it will ask the user to allow my application to do so, but this means my application will have access to everything that I have. (this is also the reason why I never allow apps to this, because I have access to to much that I dont trust other services with). So i was really hoping there was a user friendly way to allow a user to allow my application to get a token to a limited scope, like a resource group of his choosing.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The app can do everything that you can do because the app is impersonating you.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to give a service principal (not from your own AD) access to a RG within the portal, or if it has to be done using powershell ? It really would be the best way for a user to allow my app to do something on their RG without allowing it access to his full subscription

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible to do so. Please see this link for more details on how you can assign a role to a Service Principal: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/#assign-application-to-role.

Comment: i found this also, which hold some information also: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-api-authentication/